# Why does querySelectorAll() return NodeList instead of HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist, htmlcollection

I was recently learning about the `querySelectorAll()` method in JavaScript and the fact that it returns back a `NodeList` object containing all the elements that match a particular CSS selector.

Now the confusion I have is that if `querySelectorAll()` is meant to only match element nodes, why doesn't it return back an `HTMLCollection` instead, like `getElementsByClassName()` and `getElementsByTagName()` do?

**What's the point of `querySelectorAll()` returning back a `NodeList` instance?**

Is it the case that `querySelectorAll()` can be used to select non-element nodes as well?

Comment: Why *should* it return an HTMLCollection?

Comment: I *always* convert it to array

Comment: @VLAZ Because `NodeList` is a collection of nodes, whereas an `HTMLCollection` is a collection of elements.

Comment: @coderboy and so what? That's not really an argument to be made for what the result should be. Why isn't `getElementsByClassName` returning a NodeList? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: If there are two interfaces implemented by a bunch of standards craftsmen and engine developers, I guess they know of that difference. @VLAZ it's not about what difference it would make — it's about knowing why things are made the way they are.

Comment: The method is defined on Node instances, not Element instances. It's part of the `ParentNode` interface.

Comment: Maybe it's a bad design decision, or maybe it has something more sensible in it. Either way, I am looking for the reason. No doubt, this knowledge won't make ***anyone*** a better programmer.

Comment: "Why?" questions boil down to what a standards committee decided to do, quite often. There's really nothing to be done about it.

Comment: My guess would be that HTML collections can be live, which can easily become a footgun if you iterate over the collection and make modifications that lead to removal from the collection.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't dipped your toes into web scraping yet ;)